# Inset grouped cell space

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell

Is it possible to add space between cells in inset grouped style for tableview?

[image]

I need something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must define each row as a section. There was no other way for me.
If you use dynamic table view, you must use indexPath.section instead of indexPath.row